# How to specify type of build in qmake generated makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, qt-creator

I can use qt creator to debug my app. I can also run `qmake` manually on my app's `.pro` file to generate a makefile.

But, how do I get that makefile to produce a debug build (with the `-g` option in the `g++` arguments) from the command line? The makefile generated manually  doesn't build it with `-g`.

Comment: May be, it's a good idea to show the "makefile generated manually". If there really isn't any option in qt creator to create a "debug target" than you could at least edit it in a text editor to modify the make file to your requirements.

Comment: Have a look at this: [Qt: Making an Application Debuggable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-tutorial.html#making-an-application-debuggable).

Comment: by manually generated, I mean running `qmake <projectname>.pro`.

Comment: Yup, that answers my question.